# Using pow inside of a php function

Tags: php, function, variables, pow

I'm fairly new to PHP, and I seem to have hit a snag on an assignment. I'm trying to create a function that calculates the monthly payment for a simple interest loan. Here is my code.

```
function calc_payment($price, $months, $interest){
    $number = (1+($interest/12));
    $exp = pow($number, $months);
    return ($price($interest/12))/(1-$exp);
}
```

However, I'm getting an error that looks like this when I try to execute:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in (filepath) on line 5

I'm not sure what the problem is as pow is a predefined function. Oddly, this will work inside the function:

```
echo pow($number, months);
```

and give me the right data but if I try to assign it to a variable or inside the calculation it seems to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line the error is on is this:

```
($price($interest/12))/(1-$exp);
```

I think you meant this:

```
return $price*$interest/12/(1-$exp);
```

Comment: I actually just realized I needed an echo or return there. Now I'm getting an error on line 5, any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I see you haven't bothered using what I gave you. `$price` needs an operator after it, otherwise PHP thinks you're using it as a variable function name.

Comment: My mistake, I went blind after I saw the return apparently. Thanks, that appears to have worked.

Comment: This question is more about using the correct PHP Arithmetic Operators.